# Test a flow generated in a coroutine that never ends

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, ktor-client

I'm facing a problem while trying to test a class that uses coroutines to connect to a websocket using a ktor client, waits until closeReason is received and then reconnects.

This is the class

```
class Client(
    private val dispatchers: DispatcherProvider = DefaultDispatcherProvider(),
    private val httpClient: HttpClient,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(dispatchers.io())
) : CloudClient {

    val state: StateFlow<State>
        get() = connectionState

    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private val connectionState = MutableStateFlow<State>(Disconnected)

    init {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            connectionState.collectLatest {
                when (it) {
                    is State.Connected -> {
                        watchForSessionToClose((it as Connected).session)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        while (isActive && state.value == Disconnected) {
                            executeWithRetry(
                                onError = {
                                    connectionState.value = Disconnected
                                }) {
                                mutex.withLock {
                                    val socketSession = httpClient.webSocketSession()
                                    connectionState.value = Connected
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend inline fun executeWithRetry(
        maxRetries: Int = 100,
        initialDelay: Duration = Duration.ofMillis(1),
        maxDelay: Duration = Duration.ofSeconds(30),
        onError: () -> Unit,
        call: () -> Unit
    ) {
        var currentDelay = initialDelay
        for (attempt in 0..maxRetries) {
            try {
                return call()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                onError()
                if (predicate(exception) && attempt < maxRetries) {
                    delay(currentDelay.toMillis())
                    currentDelay = Duration.ofMillis(
                        (currentDelay.toMillis() * 2.0)
                            .toLong()
                            .coerceAtMost(maxDelay.toMillis())
                    )
                    continue
                } else
                    throw exception
            }
        }
    }

    private fun watchForSessionToClose(session: DefaultClientWebSocketSession) =
        coroutineScope.launch {
                val closeReason = session.closeReason.await()
                mutex.withLock { connectionState.value = Disconnected }
        }

}
```

And this would be the test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class Test {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule: CoroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule(StandardTestDispatcher())


 @Test
    fun `state should be disconnected after be connected receive a session close`() =
        runTest {
            givenACloudClient(successHttpClientAndDisconnect).state.test {
                assertTrue(awaitItem() is CloudClient.State.Disconnected)
                assertTrue(awaitItem() is CloudClient.State.Connected)
                assertTrue(awaitItem() is CloudClient.State.Disconnected)
                cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
            }
        }


    private fun givenACloudClient(httpClient: HttpClient) =
        Client(
            dispatchers = coroutineTestRule.testDispatcherProvider,
            httpClient = httpClient
        )

}
```

My problem is trying to verify the states order (Disconnected, Connected, Disconnected), turbine.test{ } is never call.

I've been debugging and the code is supposed to be working, I mean, it connects, then disconnects because the reason but quickly it connects again and so on. I'm not sure if that could be the problem or not but seems to be.

I would appreciate a hint for the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: `StateFlow`s are conflated by definition. If you update it several times, you would need to force a suspension between each update to be able to see intermediate states. I would say the test is just inappropriate here, because you're not necessarily supposed to see all transitions when observing the state flow. What you could test instead is that when you're halfway, you're in the correct state. Testing that is more difficult and may require some interesting mocking setup to control suspend/resume.

Comment: Using `emit()` instead of setting the `value` property might help too, since it suspends. Also see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3143

Comment: I will rething the test as you have mentioned because makes totally sense.